# Why is Nginx malforming redirects for IP URLS without a trailing slash?

Tags: nginx

Requests to a URL of type `10.11.13.7/admin/` work as intended.

However a request for `10.11.13.7/admin` (minus the trailing slash) attempts to redirect to `10.11.13.7,10.11.13.7/admin/` which I am assuming is NGINX trying to redirect to a URL with a trailing slash but failing for some reason.

To further confound things requests I make to `mysite.dev/admin` (mysite.dev is an entry in my local hosts file) redirect as expected, not failing as `mysite.dev,mysite.dev/admin/` which I would have suspected.

My site.conf is very minimal:

```
server {
        listen  80 default_server;

        server_name  mysite.dev www.mysite.dev;
        root /vagrant;

        client_max_body_size 64M;

        location / {

            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;

            proxy_set_header      Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        }

}
```

I suspect NGINX is the culprit and not an internal redirect issue with the application as running the app with the django manage.py development server doesn't have this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any redirect in nginx. I guess, you should fix your app

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being

```
include proxy_params;
```

had a statement that wasn't being accounted for, setting a header that caused the software to have a fit.